# Ping internal IP in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ping

I have a small CUSTOM printer that runs on IP and I want to be able to ping the device to ensure it's active from my Xamarin.iOS application. Using Reachability, I get a "true" result, even if the printer is not plugged in to the network. I've tried using the Ping class, and it simply doesn't work. I've seen some suggestions to use SimplePing, but there doesn't appear to be a recent port for Xamarin.

I figured it would be trivial to ping an IP from a Xamarin.iOS application. Am I missing something?

```
//Doesn't work on the device
public static void CheckBPStatus(string bpIP, SideMenuCallback callback)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var result = await ping.SendPingAsync(bpIP);
            if (result.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                callback.BpStatusReceived(true);
            }
            callback.BpStatusReceived(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: If the ping class fails and you know at what port the printer is listening you can emulate the ping, just try to create a TCP connection to the printer and if it fails it's not connected.

Comment: @Gusman thanks, I'll do this temporarily. The problem is that it will block any print requests while the TCP connection is open. I know it's only blocked for a short time, but I'd prefer to simply ping. Not sure why this is a limitation